# How to write a dictionary that stores non ascii characters into json file in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode

This is my first time with python and therefore sorry if the question is obvious.

Here I have a dictionary and I want to write it into a json file. To do that I did the followings :

```
result = {}
result["c2i"] = c2i # c2i is a dictionary
result["data"] = data # data is a list that stores integers
with io.open("json_test.json", 'w',encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataprocess.py", line 140, in <module>
    json.dump(result, outfile)
  File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

The content of the i2c dictionary is as follows:

```
>>> i2c
{49: '&', 50: '|',  56: '^', 57: '=', 58: '<', 59: '*', 60: '\xc2', 61: '\xa3', 62: '$', 63: '\xc3', 64: '\xa2', 65: '\xe2', 66: '\x82', 67: '\xac', 68: '\xef', 69: '\xbc', 70: '\xa6', 71: '\xaf', 72: '\xb7', 73: '>', 74: '+', 75: '\xab', 76: '\x97', 77: '~', 78: '\xad', 79: '\x98', 80: '\x86', 81: '\xb3', 82: ']', 83: '\x84', 84: '\x83', 85: '\xf0', 86: '\x9f', 87: '\x87', 88: '\xb1', 89: '\xb4', 90: '\xc4', 91: '\xb0', 92: '\xb6', 93: '[', 94: '\\', 95: '\xf3', 96: '\xbe', 97: '\x8d', 98: '\x81', 99: '\xe3', 100: '\xbb', 101: '\x8b', 102: '\xc5', 103: '\x93', 104: '\x85', 105: '\xe4', 106: '\xbd', 107: '\xa0', 108: '\xe5', 109: '\xe7', 110: '\xae', 111: '\xe9', 112: '\x9a', 113: '\x94', 114: '\xe6', 115: '\x88', 116: '\x91', 117: '\xa5', 118: '\xe8', 119: '\xb2', 120: '}', 121: '\xe0', 122: '\xb8', 123: '\xa7', 124: ':broken_heart:', 125: ':loudly_crying_face:', 126: ':black_rightwards_arrow:', 127: ':white_left_pointing_backhand_index:', 128: ':dizzy_face:', 129: ':cloud:', 130: ':white_right_pointing_backhand_index:', 131: ':heavy_black_heart:', 132: ':smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes:', 133: ':sparkling_heart:', 134: ':smiling_cat_face_with_heart-shaped_eyes:', 135: ':oncoming_bus:', 136: ':man_with_turban:', 137: ':confused_face:', 138: ':cross_mark:', 139: ':smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_tightly-closed_eyes:', 140: ':party_popper:', 141: ':open_hands_sign:', 142: ':earth_globe_asia-australia:', 143: ':sleepy_face:', 144: ':pensive_face:', 145: ':weary_face:', 146: ':smiling_face_with_sunglasses:', 147: ':droplet:', 148: ':persevering_face:', 149: ':crown:', 150: ':sleeping_face:', 151: ':musical_score:', 152: ':teacup_without_handle:', 153: ':hot_beverage:', 154: ':awe|boy:', 155: ':cocktail_glass:', 156: ':worried_face:', 157: ':thought_balloon:', 158: ':cat_face:', 159: ':personal_computer:', 160: ':splashing_sweat_symbol:', 161: ':electric_plug:', 162: ':kiss_mark:', 163: ':trophy:', 164: ':airplane:', 165: ':face_with_no_good_gesture:', 166: ':princess:', 167: ':disappointed_face:', 168: ':pouting_face:', 169: ':sparkles:', 170: ':high_voltage_sign:', 171: ':bomb:', 172: ':purple_heart:', 173: ':christmas_tree:', 174: ':black_heart_suit:', 175: ':speak-no-evil_monkey:', 176: ':woman_with_bunny_ears:', 177: ':person_bowing_deeply:', 178: ':smiling_face_with_halo:', 179: ':smiling_face_with_heart-shaped_eyes:', 180: ':beating_heart:', 181: ':unamused_face:', 182: ':ok_hand_sign:', 183: ':smiling_face_with_open_mouth:', 184: ':see-no-evil_monkey:', 185: ':face_without_mouth:', 186: ':musical_note:', 187: ':hocho:', 188: ':violin:', 189: ':smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_cold_sweat:', 190: ':basketball_and_hoop:', 191: ':person_raising_both_hands_in_celebration:', 192: ':books:', 193: ':pistol:', 194: ':happy_person_raising_one_hand:', 195: ':thumbs_up_sign:', 196: ':heart_with_arrow:', 197: ':thumbs_down_sign:', 198: ':grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes:', 199: ':weary_cat_face:', 200: ':snowflake:', 201: ':multiple_musical_notes:', 202: ':frog_face:', 203: ':umbrella_with_rain_drops:', 204: ':runner:', 205: ':winking_face:', 206: ':fire_engine:', 207: ':face_with_medical_mask:', 208: ':green_heart:', 209: ':face_with_ok_gesture:', 210: ':camera:', 211: ':french_fries:', 212: ':tropical_drink:', 213: ':smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_smiling_eyes:', 214: ':astonished_face:', 215: ':hundred_points_symbol:', 216: ':palm_tree:', 217: ':face_with_open_mouth_and_cold_sweat:', 218: ':clinking_beer_mugs:', 219: ':dash_symbol:', 220: ':flag_for_faroe_islands:', 221: ':face_with_stuck-out_tongue:', 222: ':pedestrian:', 223: ':face_throwing_a_kiss:', 224: ':raised_hand:', 225: ':confounded_face:', 226: ':dog_face:', 227: ':police_car:', 228: ':bath:', 229: ':face_screaming_in_fear:', 230: ':bust_in_silhouette:', 231: ':baseball:', 232: ':ambulance:', 233: ':squared_sos:', 234: ':wine_glass:', 235: ':imagined...re:', 236: ':face_with_tears_of_joy:', 237: ':dancer:', 238: ':clapping_hands_sign:', 239: ':heavy_large_circle:', 240: ':face_with_stuck-out_tongue_and_winking_eye:', 241: ':hatching_chick:', 242: ':open_book:', 243: ':white_smiling_face:', 244: ':fisted_hand_sign:', 245: ':tired_face:', 246: ':face_with_stuck-out_tongue_and_tightly-closed_eyes:', 247: ':snowman_without_snow:', 248: ':information_desk_person:', 249: ':two_women_holding_hands:', 250: ':two_hearts:', 251: ':angry_face:', 252: ':headphone:', 253: ':white_heavy_check_mark:', 254: ':wrapped_present:', 255: ':floppy_disk:', 256: ':soon_with_rightwards_arrow_above:', 257: ':white_frowning_face:', 258: ':grinning_face:', 259: ':black_sun_with_rays:', 260: ':crying_face:', 261: ':aubergine:', 262: ':face_savouring_delicious_food:', 263: ':victory_hand:', 264: ':flag_for_united_kingdom:', 265: ':flushed_face:', 266: ':mouse:', 267: ':rocket:', 268: ':person_with_folded_hands:', 269: ':father_christmas:', 270: ':face_with_look_of_triumph:', 271: ':nail_polish:', 272: ':skull:', 273: ':fork_and_knife:', 274: ':expressionless_face:', 275: ':growing_heart:', 276: ':microphone:', 277: ':fire:', 278: ':sleeping_symbol:', 279: ':money_bag:', 280: ':grimacing_face:', 281: ':flexed_biceps:', 282: ':smirking_face:', 283: ':pile_of_poo:', 284: ':slice_of_pizza:', 285: ':neutral_face:'}
```

I believe, the keys like '\xc2' causes problems but I couldn't find a way to deal with it. I'll use these json file from another programming language later.

**Edit: I use Python 2.7**

```
EDIT 2
```

As suggested in one of the answers, I go with second option:

```
result = {}
result[u"i2c"] = {k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in i2c.items()}
result["data"] = encoded_data
with io.open("deneme_jstonout.json", 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

However in that case, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataprocess.py", line 137, in <module>
    result[u"i2c"] = {k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in i2c.items()}
  File "dataprocess.py", line 137, in <dictcomp>
    result[u"i2c"] = {k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in i2c.items()}
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc2' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try to convert each value in the dictionary to unicode I also get an error:

**Edit 3**

```
>>> for i in i2c:
...     i2c[i] = unicode(i2c[i])
... 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: There was big changes regarding Unicode in Python between versions 2 and 3. What version are you using?

Comment: @PauloScardine 2.7

Comment: @PauloScardine when I type `>>> for i in i2c  print type(i2c[i])` all of them is printed as '<str>'

Comment: @PauloScardine with your last comment, I got the following error:  in <dictcomp>
    json.dump({k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in result.items()}, outfile)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Sorry, try `c2i = {k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in c2i.items()}`

Comment: As you suggest, I did the followign:
`i2c = {k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in i2c.items()}
result = {}
result["i2c"] = i2c
with io.open("json_test.json", 'w',encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
      json.dump(result, outfile)` but I got TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
 error @PauloScardine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, JSON is Unicode, so the json module needs string data to be of `unicode` data type data because it is unwilling to guess the encoding of your strings for you. This is a Python2 problem, in Python 3 all strings are unicode already. You have 3 choices:

### 1) Use unicode literals

```
i2c = {
    49: u'&', 
    50: u'|',  
    56: u'^', 
    57: u'=', 
    58: u'<',
    ...
    285: u':neutral_face:',
}
```

If you are importing the data from some other source (API, Database, text file), the best practice is to always decode the data into unicode when it enters your application and encode the data when it leaves the application.

### 2) Convert string data to unicode

```
 result[u"i2c"] = {k:v.decode('iso-8859-1') for k, v in i2c.items()}
 result[u"data"] = data
```

Your example does not look like UTF-8, so I guessed Latin1, but you must know the real codec because it may not be Latin1 (and anything decodes as Latin1).

### 3) Use Python3

Python 3 makes everything regarding unicode more explicit. Any io operation will give you unicode strings or bytes, so there is no ambiguity. Your program will work or not, in Python 2 the program may seem to work but explode in flames from time to time.

Comment: I edited my question according to the result I obtained by your second solution could you look at it ?

Comment: Try just `open` instead of `io.open`, the `json` module will take care of encoding for you.